# Certificate, php > 5.6 and SMTP issue

Tags: php, ssl, joomla, smtp, plesk

i have a site using joomla 3.7.4 on my server and i have set all stuffs for SMTP email. I have protected both mail, server and sites with let's encrypt certificate. All is ok and fully working.
My server has ubuntu 14.04 and Plesk Onyx and for SMTP i use postfix.

I have only important bug which i want to fix: Now i'm using php version 7.0.21 but when i try to send an email through site i have smtp error. The only way to fix is to add this code to the beginning of the function useSmtp() in joomla:

```
$this->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
  'verify_peer' => false,
  'verify_peer_name' => false,
  'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);
```

I have found this workaround here: http://toivo.talikka.com/8-joomla/15-gmail-as-smtp-server-in-joomla-3-6-0

So at every upgrade of joomla i have to add this piece of code to make email system working on site.

Any idea for a definite fix server side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to override library files is if you provide a system plugin which will register an additional library path to the autoloader. Then it should be possible to override such classes. See http://developer.joomla.org/manual/ch01s04.html for information about the autoloader and how to register own libraries.

Comment: thanks. in this way can i overide only onw function?
btw my question is about a fix server side and not client side. it's not possibile in your opinion?

thanks